# Grounding a Ballast for wood enclosure when there is no metal?

Tags: wiring, grounding

I have a big 6'x4'x3' enclosure (glass and wood) for my Tegu monitor. The external magnetic ballast for my fluorescent light broke and I would like to replace it with an electronic ballast. The external magnetic ballast plugged into an outlet, was not grounded, and did not require a ground. The electronic instant start ballast I would like to purchase requires a ground, but my fixture has no metal hood or any metal at all. If I attach the ground wire from 12/3 electrical wire, coming from an outlet, to the ballast metal housing with a screw, would that provide a proper ground? I would have a 15A 125V ground plug on the end so I can plug it into the wall. The electronic ballast would not be mounted and would be external to the fixture due to heat. Thank you!

Edit: I went ahead and purchased an extension cord and electric instant-start ballast. I hooked everything up but the light won't come on. I tried 3 different new bulbs and ran continuity checks with the wires and internal connection points. I'm not sure why it's not working. [Here are some connection pics.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ3ip.jpg) Thanks.

Edit: Everything works perfectly now. I did not know that electronic ballasts do not use a starter even after all of my research. I clipped and capped the ends where the starter was connected and the light worked perfectly.

Comment: That sounds like the way to do it.  Welcome to Home Improvement.  You can take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Get a programmed-start ballast.

Cheap ballasts also misuse ground to manipulate capacitive effects between the fluorescent tube and the *metal* enclosure.  Note huge assumption about fixture design.

Programmed-start ballasts preheat the fluorescent lamp filaments (in the ends of the tubes) until conditions are ideal to strike the arc in the manner Tesla intended.  It results in a 0.5 to 3 second startup delay (depending on ambient temperature) but is very easy on the tube, and avoids the capacitive trick.

Heat will be minimal on any modern ballast. In a fluorescent, the heat comes from the tubes.

You may want to think about LED lighting and do an end-run around all these problems.

You can't use NM cable as cordage.  If you want cordage, buy cordage.  They often sell it with a socket premolded onto the end, marketed as an "extension cord".  Make sure the writing on the side of the cord is legal for cordage, then SNIP!

Comment: I have to buy this stuff today to give my lizard proper UVB lighting. Unfortunately, I can only find an instant-start ballast that I can go pickup right now. I will order a programmed-start ballast and use that when it comes in, but I'm going to use an instant-start ballast until I get it. I'll go pickup [this extension cord](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-8-ft-16-3-Extension-Cord-Black-AW64003/206029137). I'll pickup some 12/2 romex in case the ballast wire does not reach my fixture since it's external. Thanks alot.

Comment: The issue with the instant-start is the ballast may not start, particularly once the bulbs get old.   If it does start, you can put off buying the better ballast.  I get them on eBay for $10ish.

Comment: I tried 3 different new bulbs with the instant-start ballast, but none of the lights will come on. I opened up the ballast and tested all of the lines coming in and out with my continuity function on multimeter. After running that continuity test I am confident that all of my connections are secure. Is it possible that my fixture just doesn't work with electric instant-start ballast? [connections to and from ballast](http://imgur.com/a/l2hNI)

Comment: the problem may be what I warned about: the ballast needs something electrically grounded to be running parallel to the tube about 1" away, i.e. the metal reflector most fixtures have. .  You could probably fake it with a length of ground wire.  Also make sure the ballast is wired correctly to the lampholders, it is quite different. For each end of the lampholder, take both wires and tie them to each other and also to the wire from the ballast.   A programmed start ballast will want two wires to each end, so don't tear them out lol.

Comment: I ran some ground wire coming from the ballast ground connection next to the fixture and even tried having the end of the wire touching the case of the fixture, but the light wouldn't come on. I went ahead and ordered the same magnetic ballast I had before since I know it will work.

Comment: sounds like you didn't try what I was suggesting which was to run a ground wire the length of the tube parallel to the tube and within an inch of it.  I probably wasn't clear.  anyway I'm sorry my advice did not work out for you. Best of luck.

Comment: I just tried that and the bulb partially lit. I had the ballast near the tube and it only lit on the end where the ballast was positioned. That's the best I could do; it won't light anymore. Thanks for the help. It looks like I'm going to have to replace the fixture in the future.

Comment: I needed to remove the starter because electronic ballasts do not use them unlike magnetic ballasts. I did not get this vital piece of information after all of my research, but my light works perfectly now after removing the starter. The ballast did not need to be near the fixture either. Thanks, it all worked out even though I paid the learning fee.

Comment: @Touc damn, starters.  I just conceptually think of those as "part of the ballast".  That would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The electronic ballast is intended to be connected to the safety ground wiring of building. In most modern buildings that ground is provided via a connection at the outlet as you have mentioned. So yes the cord with three prong plug is your starting place.

Even if your enclosure was made of metal or had metal parts it would not be sufficient to simply connect the ballast to those metal parts without them being in turn connected back to the safety ground at the outlet.

When you mount up the ballast and cord wiring make sure to so that in a safe way so that there is no chance of accidental damage to the wiring and that it is enclosed in suitable covering or box. The attached cord should be strain relieved so that tugs on the cord do not compromise the wiring connections.